# How to extract values from a nested Dictionary as Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

Hello stackoverflowers,

I am hoping you can help me understand an issue I am having with a nested dictionary. I scraped out some tables from an excel file: `['Table 5','Table 8',Table 40']`. What I got from the code I used was a nested dictionary which I am not sure how to handle. These are real the pains of being a beginner, I guess. My aim is to transform the values into data frames using the keys (e.g. Table 5).
The original table:
[image]

Example of dataframe:

```
d = {0: ['TB','VT','BT','CI','CH','CL','RT','RU','PV','PV','PV','PV','PV','RH','PV','PV','PV','PV','NaN','NaN','TB','VT','BT','CI','CH','CL','RT','RU','PV','PV'], 
     1: ['Table 1','BRAND. SUMMARY','Base: Floating Base (TOTAL) (18-59)','NaN','NaN','NaN','Base','Unweighted row','brand1','brand2','brand3','brand4','NPS','','NaN','Row1','Row2','Row3','NaN','NaN','Table 5','Brands Title 1','Base: All (TOTAL) (18-59)','NaN','NaN','NaN','Base','Unweighted row','Brand1','Brand2'],
     2: ['NaN','NaN','NaN','(TOTAL)','Discrete monthly banner','Sept (a)','100','997','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','NaN','0.62','0.64','0.61','0.6','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Total','19479','19608','0.75','0.75'],
     3: ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Oct (b)','1090','1100','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','NaN','0.64','0.67','0.64','0.64','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','TOTAL','Discrete monthly banner','Sept (a)','1000','1000','0.8','0.8'],
     4: ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Nov (c)','3164','3191','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','NaN','0.64','0.67','0.64','0.64','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Oct (b)','1000','1000','0.8','0.8'],
     5: ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Dec (d)','992','3999','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','NaN','0.51','0.47','0.67','0.61','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Nov (c)','1000','1000','0.8','0.8']}
```

When I print the table values and keys this is returned:

[image]

Line 174 should be my column header.

This is the code I used to **scrape** the tables from Excel:

```
ws = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Tables.xlsx', sheet_name= "Percents", header = None, usecols="B:XFD")

table_names = ["Table 5", "Table 8", "Table 9", "Table 40"]
groups = ws[1].isin(table_names).cumsum()
tables = {g.iloc[0,0]: g.iloc[1:24] for k,g in ws.groupby(groups)}
#because the syntax above (e.g.tables={g.iloc}) returned also the other values, I filtered again based on the table names
filtered_d = dict((k, tables[k]) for k in table_names if k in tables)
```

I tried to adapt this code to return my values, but when I am removing the `orient="index"` or say `orient="columns"` I am getting an error. I am thinking a for loop could do the trick.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): filtered_d[i][j] 
                           for i in filtered_d.keys() 
                           for j in filtered_d[i].keys()}, orient="index")
```

How do I solve this by keeping the curent table format and transform each value to a dataframe?

Thank you in advance for whatever advice you can give me.

Comment: Could you post your *input* data format?  I.e. just a bit of the excel spreadsheet?  I'm struggling to understand why you are scraping it in quite this way.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Hey all, @2e0byo what do you mean by input data? reproducible example? The original sheet from where I took the tables? This is the first time I am doing this so, I struggled a bit to understand how scraping works.

Comment: Ideally, post a very basic csv spreadsheet which would parse in this way.  If you can't do that, at least post a screenshot of a few rows and columns of the spreadsheet.  But much better: make an example *we can run*.  The easiest way to do that is to print out `ws` and work out the simplest dataframe which has the same dimensions (all the same columns and rows).  Then post that dataframe (perhaps with dummy data).

Comment: @2e0byo Okay, I posted a screenshot. I will post an example too. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @zabop I have added an example of a dataframe.

Comment: @2e0byo I have added an example of a data frame. Only 6 columns, the data goes on and on. :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what output you want, but with the supplied example we can have a shot.  Is this what you are after?

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['TB','VT','BT','CI','CH','CL','RT','RU','PV','PV','PV','PV','PV','RH','PV','PV','PV','PV','NaN','NaN','TB','VT','BT','CI','CH','CL','RT','RU','PV','PV'], 
     1: ['Table 1','BRAND. SUMMARY','Base: Floating Base (TOTAL) (18-59)','NaN','NaN','NaN','Base','Unweighted row','brand1','brand2','brand3','brand4','NPS','','NaN','Row1','Row2','Row3','NaN','NaN','Table 5','Brands Title 1','Base: All (TOTAL) (18-59)','NaN','NaN','NaN','Base','Unweighted row','Brand1','Brand2'],
     2: ['NaN','NaN','NaN','(TOTAL)','Discrete monthly banner','Sept (a)','100','997','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','NaN','0.62','0.64','0.61','0.6','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Total','19479','19608','0.75','0.75'],
     3: ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Oct (b)','1090','1100','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','NaN','0.64','0.67','0.64','0.64','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','TOTAL','Discrete monthly banner','Sept (a)','1000','1000','0.8','0.8'],
     4: ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Nov (c)','3164','3191','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','NaN','0.64','0.67','0.64','0.64','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Oct (b)','1000','1000','0.8','0.8'],
     5: ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Dec (d)','992','3999','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','0.31','NaN','0.51','0.47','0.67','0.61','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','Nov (c)','1000','1000','0.8','0.8']})
tbl = df.drop(range(5), axis=0).drop(0, axis=1)
print(tbl)
```

Or perhaps you want to name the rows and columns appropriately:

```py
index = tbl.iloc[:,0]
columns = tbl.iloc[0]
data = df.drop(range(6), axis=0).drop(range(2), axis=1)
tbl2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

In any case hopefully you can coerce it to the right format.

Comment: My idea was to pass the table name and get that table. Your suggestion is useful and thank you for looking into this. I will try to see how I will get on from now on. The idea is to automate this and get those tables as dataframes.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how you want it to look, but you can work out *which* rows to drop by looping through and looking for them if you need to.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear :D. The brands should be as rows, the columns are Brand Name and Months (COLS B to Y). I only need certain tables, this is why I was thinking of passing the table name and return the entire table, then I would clean the table. I know how to do them one by one, but I have about 7 files like this one and I would like to just pass the name of the table and return a data frame for that table. My logic was: get the data frame for each table, then clean it using for loops, then select the last 10 months, then add the data to PowerPoint.

Comment: I think the way to automate it is to use the table name and the `'PV'` code in the first column.